# In Ubuntu Desktop my Arduino Uno shows up as /dev/ttyACM0 .... where is it in android?

Tags: linux, command-line, usb, android

When I connect an Arduino Uno via USB to my Linux Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, the arduino shows up as /dev/ttyACM0 .... When I connect it via usb to an android phone the device is powered and recognized in Android apps, but I can't seem to find it when i look in a terminal emulator at the /dev folder. When I browse android's directory structure using terminal, where can I find the analogous device?

Further elaboration: On the desktop I can access the USB arduino device with no trouble, using

screen /dev/ttyACM0

or I can even pipe characters to it directly such as:

echo -n w > /dev/ttyACM0

On the android device, there are no tty* devices in that folder at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

That unlock OS to let the computer to erogate data/alimentation in custom mode
to the user. USeful comand for ARDUINO.

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense.